# Change Docker backoff time

Tags: docker, docker-compose

There is a foreground process in a docker container. It depends on other service (Kafka), so if Kafka fails to start, container fails to start as well.

Docker tries to restart container after 30 seconds, then 1 minute, then 2 minutes, then 4, 8, 16, 32 etc (approximately numbers).

So when I turn outer service back, docker container does not start automatically, instead it waits for these 32, 64 minutes, and that's too much.

Is there any way to change this behavior, for example, to be linear - restart attempts every 1 minute?

PS. I use `docker-compose.yml (v2)` and set option `restart: always`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/16368) on GitHub requesting an upper bound on the restart time, as well as, [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35628536/is-it-possible-to-set-maximum-delay-timeout-for-restart-policy-for-a-container/35628693) from early last year indicating that what you want is currently not possible.

Comment: Thanks! So I guess I have to catch any kind of errors in my application service and retry manually, and don't rely on Docker

Comment: It was fixed. The maximum time is now 1min.